# How to get state from zustand

Tags: reactjs, state, zustand

I have a filter object in store and function setFilter to change filter. I use the immer middleware.
Can you explain what different between this:

```
  const { filter, setFilter } = useFilterStore()
```

and

```
  const { filter, setFilter } = useFilterStore((state) => ({
    filter: state.filter,
    setFilter: state.setFilter,
  }))
```

two methods is working fine

Comment: The first one will rerender whenever anything in the store is updated. The second one will only rerender if `filter` or `setFilter` is updated.

Comment: what do you mean 'rerender'? please give me some example

Comment: In second it will also render on any state update because you on every state update, selector returns an new object reference. To fix this, you can to pass shallow as second argument in useFilterStore. You can import shallow from zustand `import { shallow } from 'zustand/shallow';